# Link href to the next div with anchorpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to link to the next div with an anchor point.

Currently i have an a href that directs the user to the second `div` (`#div2`) via an anchor point, like this:

```
<a href="#div2">Arrow down</a>
```

How do i make this arrow link to the following `div`?

So if the user is focused on the `#div2` i want it to link to `#div3`, when it's on `#div3` i want it to link to `#div4`, etc.

Bonus goal: when the last `div` is reached (let's say `#footer`) i want it to point back up to `#div1`

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers, i have made a JSfiddle to make it more clear:
https://jsfiddle.net/dj5p82bg/

Comment: it can simply accomplished by JQ.

Comment: please share the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Without your effort question is use less. I can say **Yes** its possible.

Comment: How could we know without seeing your HTML structure?

Comment: With the given conditions, `#footer` will never be reached ; ). You've also to explain, where/how you're going to use the answer, are you creating these links dynamically? Or in a template? I'm sure you're not asking, how to write the literal links to your file?

Comment: are you dynamically creating this HTML? if so then not without JS. If you are hard coding then this is possible.

Comment: @gurvinder372 here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dj5p82bg/

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go Brian

```
$(".linkdiv").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr("id", "linkdiv"+index);
    var text = index === $(".linkdiv").length -1 ? "first" : "next";
  var next = index === $(".linkdiv").length -1 ? 0 : index+1;
  $("<a href='#linkdiv"+next+"'>Go to "+text+"</a>").insertBefore(this);
});
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vhscLLz/)

Comment: @BrianV happy to help. if this is what you're looking for please hit the checkmark by my answer.

Comment: Thank you! very nice code. (sorry for double answer, i did not mean to press enter, only shift+enter for new line)

The only problem is, i did not manage to make this working on the website because of the fixed navigation arrow.

I have something like this:
<div class="nav-arrow">
        <a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></a></div>

Which has the following CSS:
width:40px;
height:40px;
position:fixed;
top:30%;
right:5px;
z-index:100;

Is it possible to change the anchorpoint link (#about) to the next div?

Comment: if you need help understanding basic javascript you need to google for tutorials, not ask in the comments on SO.. good luck.